# Laravel 5.1 blade template not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

my blade template is not working on my laravel 5, i have just installed laravel 5.1 and then when i type codes like @yield() or @extends() the text's dont have color it is just plain white like just some regular text, am i doing it wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
@yield('') "its color is white, looks like just plain text"
  </body>
   </html>


      //Dont mind this, i used this bcoz i have errors submitting this
                        width: 100%;
            display: table;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .container {
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 96px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">Laravel 5</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You've provided a blade template and normal html file in to one code block?

Comment: when i type blade template codes like @yeild() <- this doesnt color in my sublime editor, so i assume its not working

Comment: It doesn't colour in for mine either, and I use sublime editor too. It doesn't mean that it won't render on the page though. As long as your file is set up with the `blade.php` extension it will be rendered by Laravel.

Comment: oh ok thanks, i was confused because the last time i used lara was version 4. and it colours on my sublime, but well ok thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stock standard Sublime Text editor won't give highlight blade syntax as this is specific to Laravel and Sublime is a general code editor.

You can add a package in to achieve what you're after though, [Laravel Blade Highlighter](https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade) seems to be the go for this.

Check out the link above for steps on how to add this to Sublime.

Once it is installed it will provide blade syntax highlighting.

Comment: another one, how do i enable bootstrap in laravel 5.1?

Comment: You don't enable in it in a literal sense, you just include it as a stylesheet for you project. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp gives a good run down of the two ways you can add it.

Comment: oh well ok, i thought laravel is built in with bootstrap, so ill just do it like normal coding? ill jus need to link it?

Comment: @user3352042 it ships with its own version of bootstrap which you can link to by using `<link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> `